# What to learn to make a photo gallery site like this?

Tags: photo-gallery

I started a Wordpress site for my blog but now I want to start another domain for sharing my photos. I used to use Flickr but it requires you to sign up for Flickr Pro if you want to upload over a certain amount of photos. Since I don't want to pay for that, I'm looking to create a photo gallery site like this:

http://10mmgalore.com/ or http://www.shuttermaki.com/

But how do you go about with that? Would I be able to install Wordpress and find a theme like that? And/Or are there any Wordpress plugins that I can install to make it like look like that? Or do I need different tools and platforms asides from Wordpress?

So can someone list the features, tools and information that I need to make a photo gallery site?

The main functions that I want for my site is to have a picture in the middle and when the user clicks on the photo, it goes to the next photo; or there are left and right arrows that users can click to the next photo. I just want to create an album website for my 365 days project (a photo a day). It doesn't have to be as fancy as the sites mentioned above. Thank you!

Comment: Wordpress was originally made for blogging.. and in your case I don't think wordpress would help. Photo galleries can either be made/written (if you are sure going to make with your own) in  flash or in JavaScript. Just Google these terms.

Comment: this link might help if you are too lazy http://www.zenphoto.org/